# icon not showing in html

Tags: html, css

I am making a website by watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYRda7UtuhA&t=490s. timing: 25:10. I did as shown in the video, but the icons on the site are not displayed for me. When I add these commands, my section texts are moved to the center. and there are no icons. I looked on the Internet to solve this problem, but I did not find anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>InkoGreat Website - Everything about programming</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
family=Anek+Odia:wght@100;300;500;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome- 
free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<section class="header">
    <nav>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/profile-logo.jpg"></a>
        <div class="nav-links">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="">COURSE</a></li>
                <li><a href="">BLOG</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
    </nav>
<div class="text-box">
    <h1>Welcome to InkoGreat's website!</h1>
    <p>This site publishes useful programs for programming,
    new chips, tips and much more!<br>Python/HTML/CSS/JavaScript</p>
    <a href="" class="hero-btn">Visit Us To Know More</a>
</div>

</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The font link gives invalid url. Check for errors in your console.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `font-awesome` cdn url to `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css`. The link used by you seems to be invalid. Changing the link should solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

This thing has happened multiple times to me. Most of the time, when using Edge, it does not display the icons.
This is probably a compatibility issue. So you are recommended to remove the line
`<link rel="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-  free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css">`. As a developer, a more recommended way is to go to https://fontawesome.com/start (The latest version of FontAwesome) and create an ID. There, you will have more customisability to your icon pack and hence, make your icon pack light. You will also be provided with an option to add a js file in the HTML file which works without any problems.

Answer (score -1):

If you're facing the same issue, I have a simple fix. Just update your Font Awesome link to this:
[https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css]
I tried it, and it works like a charm on both Chrome and Mozilla. Hope this saves you some time and hassle!